# Cómo insertar los mismos registros de una tabla con nuevo ID y actualizar solo una columna

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buen día, tengo la siguiente duda, quisiera insertar los mismos registros de una tabla cuando le doy clic a un botón y que se se inserte con un nuevo ID y los mismos datos de las columnas, salvo una que se llama Año, este se actualizaria a través de un input y ese año se actualizaria para cada uno de los registros nuevos a insertar en la tabla, no tengo ninguna idea de como realizarlo, alguien a realizado algo parecido? Desde ya muchas gracias

tengo la siguiente linea de codigo para la consulta mysql

```
INSERT INTO israsimilados(sueldoinf,sueldosup,limiteinf,limitesup,coutafija,porcentaje,anio,tipo) SELECT sueldoinf,sueldosup,limiteinf,limitesup,coutafija,porcentaje,anio,tipo FROM israsimilados;
```

Esta consulta me duplica los datos en la misma tabla sin problema, pero quisiera saber ahora como ponerle una condicion para que solo me actualice los registros que tienen por anio 2020 a 2021, lo intente poniendole un SET luego del select pero no funciona

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Cómo podría duplicar todos los registros de una tabla e insertarlos en la misma con el ID diferente y el campo años actualizado.

Comment: duplicar o actualizar? como esta tu tabla, y como queres que quede?

Comment: Eh editado la pregunta, ahora ya duplica datos pero me duplica todos y quisiera que solo me duplique los registros que tienen por anio 2020... haciendo un update a 2021

Comment: un set? leiste como es el insert? solo agrega un where. Y cambia el año a mano ,y ponele 2021...

Comment: Si lei como es el insert pero no logre dar con el resultado requerido, pudieras ayudarme con la sentencia?

Comment: si, si mostras como esta tu tabla, y como queres que quede, si.. pero sigo sin entender al 100% que queres hacer...

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución para ello use una tabla temporal para filtrar los datos por el año y luego de ello actualicé la tabla temporal del año 2020 a 2021 y por ultimo lo volví a insertar a la misma tabla omitiendo el campo ID debido a que mi tabla tiene autoincrement por lo que lo hace automaticamente anexo la sentencia mySQL

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT Estado,Porcentaje,Descripcion, anio from impuestosnomina WHERE anio=2020;
UPDATE tmp SET anio=2021 WHERE anio = 2020;
INSERT INTO impuestosnomina (Estado,Porcentaje,Descripcion,anio) SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE anio = 2021;
```

Gracias!